# Given a sequence find the shortest reg exp that generates it?

Tags: ds.algorithms, fl.formal-languages, regular-expressions

I'm looking for a way to find the smallest possible regular-expression that accepts a sequence.

To make it interesting I don't want any stars(Kleene stars) and preferably no wildcards?

For instance the sequence : 'aaaaaaaa' would be accepted by 'a^8' and a^8 would be the shortest possible expression to accept the sequence.

Does anyone body know how to generate such an expression?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to say generates and not accepts?

Comment: You have to define the grammar of the “regular expressions” you are talking about.  r^n (where r is a regular expression and n is an integer) is usually not considered as an integral part of regular expressions, at least in theoretical computer science, because it can be easily replaced by the n repetition of r.

Comment: What have you **trie** d?

Comment: @JɛﬀE once I have build a trie, how do I know what nodes to pick as sub expressions?